# Enter в Textarea выполняет функцию

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии <kbd>Enter</kbd> выполнялась функция

```
<textarea type="text" maxlength="12" id="textbox" placeholder="ID пользователя"></textarea>
<button id="add-friend">✔</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function enter() {
  console.log('Выполняем функцию')
}
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    e.preventDefault()
    enter()
    return
  }
})
```

```html
<textarea type="text" maxlength="12" id="textbox" placeholder="ID пользователя"></textarea>
```